# Having Issue on Getting Uploaded File Name by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to get the name of the file(image)

```js
$('input:file').on('change', function(){
  console.log($(this).prop("files")['name']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="test" />
```

As you can see I am getting `undefined` in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this).prop("files")` returns a `FileList`, not a single file.

You'd need to do:

```
$(this).prop("files")[0]['name']
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList